# Custom Validation service for null property

Tags: angular

Am using angular 10

```
email(control: AbstractControl) {
  if ( control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return { 'invalidEmailAddress': true };
  }
}
```

Above is validation sevice for email address..it is perfecly fine for below case in component

```
  email: ['', this.ser.mail],
```

Not working for below case

```
 email: [null, this.ser.email],
```

Email is optional field but validation should work..

Please let me know what should be needed for include null case ?

**EDIT: i tried for below code in email service**

```
 if( control.value.match(/null/))
  return null;
```

but no luck

Comment: you are using angulars ibuilt email validator not your custom,

try this => 

email: [null, [this.email]],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if( !control.value || control.value===null)
  return null;
```

Comment: pleasure. Don't forget to select the check if it's the right answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

As in comment you should use built in [EmailValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator) for email validation.
but in future if u want to create custom validator keep in mind that it should do just one thing. in your case it should just validate if its invalid email or not, and if its required, it job of required validator

how we can do it ?
in this simple example we can change code to:

```
email(control: AbstractControl) {
    if(!!control.value){   
        if ( control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidEmailAddress': true };
        }
    }
}
```